# NSString Unicode display

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to look at the display of a number of Unicodes using a forLoop.  However the compiler doesn't like "%x" or "%d" in the string to build a Unicode.  Is there a work around?

```
for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++){
    lbl.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u00B%x", k ];// <-- incomplete universal character name \u00B
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure a fully understand what you're trying to achieve. For this answer, I assume that you want to generate the Unicode characters int the range between B0 and BF.

Your code doesn't work due to the `\u` escape sequence (and not because of the `%x` or `%d` format specifiers). Just read the error message carefully. The code assumes that the `%x` specifier will be substituted with a number first and that the escape sequence will be evaluated second. However, it happens the other way round: First the `\u` sequence is evaluated by the compiler and an error thrown because it is invalid.

A better (and simpler) approach is the following code:

```
for (unichar ch = 0xB0; ch <= 0xBF; ch++){
    lbl.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", ch ];
}
```

This code directly puts a Unicode character into the string.

Comment: Can the %C handle 32bit wide unicode such as the charcode of an emoji character？

Comment: I don't think though. According to the documentation, it's restricted to 16 bit. And the emoji characters are outside that range.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method instead:

```
NSString stringWithUTF8String:
```

From the documentation here on the section Strings and Non-ASCII Characters:

[Formatting Strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943)