# Unicode character in object C

Tags: ios, objective-c, emoji

I want to print Unicode character in objective C like `NSString s="\ue415"`.
http://www.easyapns.com/iphone-emoji-alerts
Now I have the code `e415`, how can I append this code with `\u` to print the Emotion, I try to append but I only can get the `NSString` `\ue415` not the unicode character.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6839326/2016778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xcode and clang toolchain allow the use of UTF-8 encoded source files since a while. So just enter the emoticon using a string literal.

Just open your source file and type something like...

```
NSString *message = @"  ";
```

You can enter emoticons using the system wide special character panel. Open it in Xcode using ⌘⌥ T.

Comment: i'm newbie in Xcode, can you show me some steps or an example? Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very much. But this is not what I want to ask, I already know how to using string literal. I want to know how to append string "\u" with "e405", "e407" (for example, i have an array like this) to print a unicode character but I only can get a String "\ u e 4 0 7".